# Echo statement giving empty output

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

i have the following Code, but it is giving empty output for the echo statement "echo $dirname" when i type in the same command in CLI it is showing correct output but while running as script giving empty output .

```
for folderpath in `find /u01/app/SrcFiles/commercial/ngdw/* -name "IQ*"`;
do
    folder_count=`ls -d $folderpath/* | wc -l`
    echo -e "Total Date folder created : $folder_count in $folderpath \n"
    
    if [ $folder_count -ne 0 ];
    then
        for dirpath in `find $folderpath/* -name "2*" `;
        do  
            dirname=${dirpath##*/}
            (( dirname <= 20210106 )) || continue
            echo $dirname 
            
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: Your script works fine for me.  Try running it with bash -x to give yourself some debug output.  Perhaps you've got something off in your environment.

Comment: When i reun with bash -x . It is not taking the dirname value

+ for dirpath in '$(find $folderpath/* -name "2*")'
+ dirname=
+ ((  dirname <= 20210106  ))
+ echo